# Output shape or tensor of tensorflow Dense and LayerNormalization layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch, tensor

I am trying to apply some layer normalization and some dense layering to some tensors that i have, but when I try to get an output and see what the tensors might look like after this I get a strange output. For reference, I have done the same using pytorch and in that case I can output the tensors and see the shape, but when I attempt the same with tensorflow the output i get is <keras.layers.normalization.layer_normalization.LayerNormalization object at 0x7f91f862abf0>.

Here is the pytorch code that works:

```
data = [3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17]
aux_idxs_torch = torch.tensor(data)
layer_norms_torch = nn.ModuleList([])
linear_layers_torch = nn.ModuleList([])
for i in aux_idxs_torch:
    layer_norms_torch.append(nn.LayerNorm([2*i, 100]))
    linear_layers_torch.append(nn.Linear(2*i, 128))
print(layer_norms_torch[0].weight.shape)
print(linear_layers_torch[0].weight.shape)
```

This code outputs: torch.Size([6, 100]) and torch.Size([128, 6])

And here is the tensorflow that I am attempting. What can I write differently to get a proper shape outputted? Or is the mistake that it is wrong while the pytorch code is correct?

```
data = [3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17]
aux_idxs_tf = tf.constant(data)
layer_norms_tf = []
linear_layers_tf = []
for i in aux_idxs_tf:
    layer_norms_tf.append(tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(input_shape=(2*i, 100)))
    linear_layers_tf.append(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, input_shape=(2*i,)))
print(layer_norms_tf[0])
print(linear_layers_tf[0])
```

This code outputs <keras.layers.normalization.layer_normalization.LayerNormalization object at 0x7f91f862abf0> and <keras.layers.core.dense.Dense object at 0x7f91f87eb7f0>.

Unfortunately, for this task I must use tensorflow, not pytorch

As an addition, printing out the entire tensor for each gives me for pytorch:

```
ModuleList(
  (0-3): 4 x LayerNorm((tensor(6), 64), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
  (4): LayerNorm((tensor(8), 64), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
  (5-8): 4 x LayerNorm((tensor(6), 64), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
  (9): LayerNorm((tensor(8), 64), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
  (10-21): 12 x LayerNorm((tensor(16), 64), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
  (22-28): 7 x LayerNorm((tensor(32), 64), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
  (29): LayerNorm((tensor(34), 64), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
)
```

And for tensorflow it gives me:

```
[<keras.layers.normalization.layer_normalization.LayerNormalization object at 0x7f91f8507d00>, <keras.layers.normalization.layer_normalization.LayerNormalization object at 0x7f91f85bd3f0>, <keras.layers.normalization.layer_normalization.LayerNormalization object at 0x7f91b71fdc00>]
```

What I am really trying to do is make sure that both are working the same way, but I cannot confirm this since the outputs are so different. Is there something I can do to get similar outputs using both frameworks?

Comment: You are not printing the same things, in PyTorch you print the weights shape, in TensorFlow you are printing the layer objects.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I updated my explanation to add more info of what i want. Youre right I didnt explain that. I am trying to somehow confirm that both codes are working in the same way